# Spring Batch Integration, Email to be sent out in case of JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I would like to put a hook somewhere in the following code/config to be able to spot a `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` and then email the production support team that this occurred.

I have tried a `JobExecutionListener#beforeJob()` method in Spring Batch, but the `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` is occurring before job execution.

I am using this Spring Batch Integration configuration from the documentation:

```
<int:channel id="inboundFileChannel"/>
<int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filePoller"
    channel="inboundFileChannel"
    directory="file:/tmp/myfiles/"
    filename-pattern="*.csv">
<int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>

</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transformer input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
    output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">
    <bean class="io.spring.sbi.FileMessageToJobRequest">
       <property name="job" ref="personJob"/>
       <property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.name"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>
```

I want to handle `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` in case the same CSV file name appears as the job parameter. Do I extend `org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler`?

I notice that class is reporting the error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={input.file.name=C:\Users\csv\file2015.csv}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler` is done from the default `errorChannel` which is reached from the `<poller>` on your `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

So, to handle it manually your just need to specify your own `error-channel` there a go ahead with email sending:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="sendErrorToEmailChannel"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter id="sendErrorToEmailChannel"/>
```

Of course, you will have to do some `ErrorMessage` transformation before sending ti over e-mail, but that is already details of the target business logic implementation.